# Is it possible to restrict the type of a List to an implementation of an interface in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a class `Stealth` implementing the interface `Skill` and a class `SoundlessMovement` implementing the interface `Mastery`. Now I want to add the mastery `SoundlessMovement` to the `Skill` `Stealth`, while ensuring the `Mastery` to be supported by the `Skill`.

I want to do something like this (Pseudo-Kotlin):

```
interface Skill {
    val masteries: List<Mastery<Skill>> // Mastery linked to type Skill
}
```

and

```
interface Mastery<Skill> { // Every Mastery must be compatible with only one Skill
    val masteryName: String
}
```

with implementations:

```
class Stealth : Skill {
    override val masteries: ArrayList<Mastery<Stealth>() // Any Mastery bound to Stealth
}
```

and

```
class SoundlessMovement : Mastery<Stealth> { // Is a Mastery compatible with Stealth
    override val masteryName = "Soundless Movement"
}
```

The goal is to make sure that only compatible masteries can be added to a skill.
Is something like this even possible? And if yes, how could it be implemented in Kotlin?

Comment: I am aware that the title of the question is bad. I just don't have any idea how to better describe the problem.

Comment: Your class design is not understandable.  Why  `Mastery` need a generic parameter but not using it? Why is Skill hold a list reference to its class? Can you explain what you want to achieve and your class relationship.

Comment: @Joshua The structure is simplified to only show the problematic part of the code. In simple terms I try to have a class implementing an interface which holds a list with the type of another class implementing another interface and being bound to the first class. The goal is to prevent mixing of skills and masteries by binding each mastery to a specific skill.

So Pelocho's answer is exactly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I really understood you but I think this piece of code solves your problem:

```
interface Mastery<Skill> {
    val masteryName: String
}

interface Skill<Self : Skill<Self>> {                              // forces every Skill to bound to itself
    val masteries: List<Mastery<Self>>
}

abstract class Stealth : Skill<Stealth> {
    override val masteries = ArrayList<Mastery<Stealth>>()
}

class SoundlessMovement : Mastery<Stealth> {         // a Stealth mastery
    override val masteryName = "Soundless Movement"
}

class SoundlessMovement2 : Mastery<Stealth> {        // another Stealth mastery
    override val masteryName = "Soundless Movement 2"
}

abstract class Archery : Skill<Archery> {         
    override val masteries = ArrayList<Mastery<Archery>>()
}

class SureShot : Mastery<Archery> {                  // some other mastery
    override val masteryName = "Sure shot 2"
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    var list = ArrayList<Mastery<Stealth>>()

    list.add(SoundlessMovement())            // compiles
    list.add(SoundlessMovement2())           // compiles
    list.add(SureShot())                     // Doesn't compile
}
```

The key here is to use `Skill<Self>` to bound the current implementations. Note also that I've changed `class Stealth ...` to `abstract class Stealth ...` since you're *defining* the mastery type. Another option could be using [Kotlin's sealed class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html)

Beware that `Self` **is not** a reserved word nor anything similar. The code will also work if you just change it to just `T`. I chose to use `Self` just to make you aware what type you should put there

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. It also explains why I've never heard of it. It is better readable than `Foo<T : Foo<T>>` though. Now that I know `Self` is not a keyword, I also understand, what the code does. It's even simpler than I thought.